# IllegalAccessException in public attribute of a inner  class

Tags: java, playframework, inner-classes, access-modifiers, playframework-1.x

I was building a class using play framework 1.2.x .

I have a Controller class which contains a non-anonymous(named) private inner class.

When I try to access one of the public fields of the inner class via its constructor I get the following error [image: NonAnonymous Inner class access exception]

The above code

```
private static class FinancialTransactionJSONPacket implements JSONPacket{
    public final boolean isSuccess;
    public final List<FinancialTransaction> financialTransactions;
    public final  OPERATIONS operation;

    public FinancialTransactionJSONPacket(boolean isSuccess,FinancialTransaction financialTransaction,OPERATIONS operation) {           
        this(isSuccess,new ArrayList<FinancialTransaction>(),operation);
/* Line 43 */   this.financialTransactions.add(financialTransaction);           
    }
}
```

I don't get the Logic , how is this even possible ? I am accessing an attribute of a class from within its constructor how do access specifiers matter ?

I tried searching and found [this article](http://blog.mograbi.info/2010/08/play-framework-cannot-access-public.html) but it relates to anonymous Inner Classes, and the solution proposed is to make the anonymous inner class as a named class.

Declarations

- `public final List<FinancialTransaction> financialTransactions;`
- `private static class FinancialTransactionJSONPacket`

Comment: Code is illegible. Please post it here as formatted text.

Comment: Ok Added the code as formatted text

Comment: Whats the issue with the question , why the -1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static class is private, so only the enclosing class can access its members, whether they are public or not.

I can't see any evidence in your illegible graphic that the access is happening within the static class's own constructor. It looks when I peer at it more like an external class is trying to access the class's innards.

NB This is not an inner class, because it is static.

Comment: I cannot make the image any bigger on the page, Please click on it , and it will open the full sized one.

Comment: @GautamK OK I did that. It just confirms my answer. You are asking the wrong question here.

Comment: `financialTransactions` is a `public` `final` attribute of the inner class, and I am accessing it from the inner class's constructor , now what is wrong in that ?

Comment: @GautamK That's not what it says in the stack trace. Have a good look. The stack trace talks about an external class trying to access the field.

Comment: But I don't even know what that class is ? why is it accessing my code ?

Comment: I tried making the class as `protected` instead of `private` and That solved it ! But  I still cannot understand what `$FieldAccessors` doing accessing my class ?

Comment: @GautamK I don't know why we are expected to explain your own exception to you. It is quite clear, and it has nothing to do with the constructor you keep mentioning. Print the stack trace and see what's happening for yourself.